# Update password test with Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

i am writing a test for update password!
here is my code:

```
 def update_password
if @current_user.update(user_params)
  # Sign in the user by passing validation in case their password changed
  # sign_in @user, :bypass => true
  json_success("Password successfully updated")
else
  json_not_found("#{ @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}")
end
```

end

and my test is:

```
context 'update password' do
  def update_password
    patch :update_password, { password: 'password',
                              password_confirmation: 'password' }
  end

  it 'should update user password on user request' do
    expect(user.valid_password?('password')).to eq(false)
    update_password
    user.reload
    puts response.body.inspect
    expect(user.valid_password?('password')).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

but i am keep getting an error:

```
 1) Api::V2::UsersController patch #update_password update password should update user password on user request
 Failure/Error: expect(user.valid_password?('password')).to eq(true)

   expected: true
        got: false

   (compared using ==)
```

and one more questing how will a pass a json header with authenticate token in it: thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your spec and controller should be something closer to this and this should **HELP** you get past that error. **There could be a variety of other errors i can't see with @user or @current_user**

```
# app/controllers/some_controller.rb
def update_password
  if @current_user.update(user_params)
    render json: "Password successfully updated"
  else
    render json: @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
  end
end

# spec/controllers/some_controller.rb
describe SomeController, type: :controller do
  it '#update_password' do
    params = double(:params, password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')
    current_user = double(:current_user)
    expect(current_user).to receive(:update).with(params).and_return(true)
    patch :update_password, params
    expect(response.body).to eq "Password successfully updated"
  end
end
```

> one more questing how will a pass a json header with authenticate token in it: thanks

^^ should be a different SO question